# Can I use NSPredicate for this?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Here's my loop:

```
- (NSArray *)myArray
{
    if (!_myArray)
    {
        NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];

        for (MyReport *report in self.helper.myReportType.reports)
        {
            [array addObject:report.nameString];
        }        
        _myArray = array;
    }

    return _myArray;
}
```

This works (with obviously some casting happening, which may not be great or desirable), but surely there's a better way to do this. Can `NSPredicate` help here? (I'm still new to using `NSPredicate`, but I believe it's primarily for filtering data, not building an array like this?) Otherwise, how can I rewrite this using another Apple helper class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSPredicate` is more about filtering data, like you said. A clean way to do this is with Key-Value Coding, which when used on `NSArray`, calls the `valueForKey:` method on each of its objects, and returns the results as an `NSArray`:

```
_myArray = [self.helper.myReportType.reports valueForKey:@"nameString"];
```

Note that this method converts `nil` to `NSNull` automatically. More advanced KVC-Collection operator information can be found here: http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/

Comment: Is this call safe if `self.helper.myReportType.reports` is an empty array (say, `[NSArray array]` for example)?

Comment: To answer my own question- yes, it's safe if its an empty array. In such an event, this method will simply return an empty array back. Thanks for the quick answer. This is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code-

```
[self.helper.myReportType.reports valueForKey:@"nameString"];
```

It will return you array of nameString's from reports array.